# Expansão atrasada no corpo do laço for usando a opção /f

Tags: batch

Reduzi o código para ser breve:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a n_tokens=2

for /f "tokens=!n_tokens! delims=\" %%s in ("Program\Executable") do (
    echo %%s
) 

pause > nul
```

Sei que nesse contexto não seria necessário usar exclamações (!!) para expandir a variável, mas no contexto que preciso é.

Ao usar a delayed expansion recebo o erro "tokens=!n_tokens! foi inesperado", gostaria de saber qual é o problema que acontece e alguma solução também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pesquisei no StackOverFlow em inglês e achei um [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973243/issue-with-for-loop-and-delayed-expansion) dizendo que simplesmente não é aceito delayed expansion no corpo do for, então resolvi usar a sugestão dada pelo usuário em uma das respostas:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a n_tokens=1

:: Este é um exemplo resumido do que eu tentava
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%s in ("Prog\Exe") do (
    set /a n_tokens=2

    for /f "tokens=!n_tokens! delims=\" %%s in ("Prog\Exe") do (
        REM erro !n_tokens! foi inesperado
    )
)

:: Solução que encontrei
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%s in ("Prog\Exe") do (
    set /a n_tokens=2

    call :Func
    REM Continuar o código...
)
goto end


:Func
:: Essa função é chamada após a atualização da variável n_tokens

for /f "tokens=%n_tokens% delims=\" %%s in ("Prog\Exe") do (
    echo %%s
    REM imprime corretamente "Exe" (segundo token de "Prog\Exe")
)

goto :eof

:end
pause > nul
```